# XML parsing tool

Tags: xml, openstreetmap

I need to make some XML manipulation within OpenStreetMap project. Input will be [XAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/XAPI) tag search result (XML file), which I can save and load locally. I need to extract a parameter from a tag in one file and save it as a differently named parameter of a differetly named tag in another file. The output can also be text only for copy&paste into [RawEditor](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RawEditor).

For illustration a simplified samlpe input file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis SNAPSHOT-r26564">
  <tag-to-be-ignored id="253657034" version="2">
    <tag k="created_by" v="Merkaartor 0.12"/>
  </tag-to-be-ignored>  
  <way id="86815694" version="2" timestamp="2010-11-28T09:35:28Z" uid="134948" user="alik" changeset="6476298">
    <nd ref="952980925"/>
    <nd ref="953396365"/>
    <tag k="dibavod:id" v="416520000100"/>
    <tag k="source" v="dibavod"/>
  </way>
  <another-tag-to-be-ignored></another-tag-to-be-ignored>
</osm>
```

Desired output:

```
<relation>
  <member type="way" ref="86815694" role=""/>
    <tag k="key" v="name"/>
</relation>
```

There are multiple "way" tags in input file all desired to be included in the output. There are also multiple tag (other than "way") to be ignored. Is there a Windows tool for this? If not, what would be the easiest way to code this as a standalone executable (command-line tool?) or a web script? I have some very limited programming skills.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: XSLT is definitely what you're looking for. It takes one XML sheet and transforms it (using user defined criteria) into another type. For Windows, checkout [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). For Linux, checkout [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

Comment: Reading this question I'm quite curious to know *why* you want to do this thing (creating relations in a semi-automated manner via the RawEdit interface) There are many pitfalls to automated and semi-automated editing of OpenStreetMap, and many ways of making a mess on the OpenStreetMap server. Have you discussed your plans with the OpenStreetMap community?

Comment: @Harry: yes, this is about an import that has been well discussed in my local community (CZE).

Answer (score 2):

This is what [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) and [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xquery) were made for.